# For testing purposes, how can I set the event.originalEvent.detail that click() creates?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a followup to this question: [Space and enter "click" on the input that's focused. How do I disable this behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20849022/61624)

The solution is to check for `event.originalEvent.detail` in my handlers.  The problem is, I call `click()` many times in my unit tests and apparently the events that are passed from it don't contain a `event.originalEvent` in them.  For my tests, I'd like to be able to mock this field.

I'm thinking the easiest way to do this would be to get the `event` that `click()` normally creates and pass that into [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) instead.  The problem is, I don't know how to get the event that `click()` normally creates.  Or, is there an even easier way to handle this?

Comment: maybe you are looking for creating event object as given [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3911640/manually-creating-a-javascript-event-object)

Comment: How exactly are you triggering the clicks in your unit tests?

Comment: @Johan like this: `$(selector).click();`

Comment: Why not simply do `var event = e || e.originalEvent;`?